# how to pass function as parameter in a method

Tags: c#

As the heading says, how do I achieve that? So far this is what I have. I am trying to pass `SavePermission` function in `radsave_click` method.

```
private void SavePermission(string profileID, string featureID, string ActionID)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())   
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_perm_insert";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pprofileID", Convert.ToInt64(profileID));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfeatureID", Convert.ToInt64(featureID));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pActionID", Convert.ToInt64(ActionID));
        int result1 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I need to pass this as a parameter in this method.

```
private void radbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int iRow = 0;

        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to apply these changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in kryptonDataGridViewAction.Rows)
            {
                SavePermission(profileID1, featureID, ActionID);

                string strpro;
                strpro = kryptonDataGridProf.SelectedRows[0].Cells["profileID"].Value.ToString();

                string strfeat;
                strfeat = kryptonDataGridViewAction.Rows[iRow].Cells["featureID"].Value.ToString();

                string strAct;
                strAct = kryptonDataGridViewAction.Rows[iRow].Cells["ActionID"].Value.ToString();

                //string strAct_name;
                //strAct_name = kryptonDataGridViewAction.Rows[iRow].Cells["ACTIONS"].Value.ToString();

                //       MessageBox.Show(strpro, "");
                //       MessageBox.Show(strpro+ " /" + strfeat + " /" + strAct );
                iRow = iRow + 1;
            }
            //  MessageBox.Show("Changes has successfully been applied", "Applying Changes", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Comment: You can't alter the event handler's signature.

Comment: what should i do then

Comment: I've just posted an answer.

Comment: Why do you  need to do this?  Can't you just call the `SavePermission` method directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter the `radbtnSave_Click` event handler's signature, but you could use a delegate *within* your event handler, like this:

```
var a = new Action<string, string, string>(SavePermission);
```

And then use it like this:

```
a("my profile ID", "my feature ID", "my action ID");
```

Or you could just call the method directly:

```
SavePermission("my profile ID", "my feature ID", "my action ID");
```

I guess I don't really understand why you need to pass the method itself.